# Can we implement metal framework in CPP

Tags: c++, metal

I am planning to implement iOS metal library in CPP. This library is meant to expose high level API's that can be used other modules. Does Metal expose CPP level api that i can use in my library?

Comment: **What kind of program are your coding?** Will it have some web interface? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64853405/edit) your question to provide *a lot more details*, perhaps even some [mre]

Comment: Also, explain what is the size of your team (dozen of developers, hundreds of them) and of your code base (a thousand lines of source code, or a million lines of them)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Objective C++ if you want to use C++ for your logic. There is no pure C++ interface.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provide [metal-cpp](https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp) which provides direct access to the Metal API from C++.  One downside appears to be that manual reference counting must be used, like the bad old days.  This is probably not much of an issue if you use wrapper classes around the Metal objects.

At the moment, however, I use Objective-C++ to provide a C++ interface to Metal and this does work with ARC; i.e. in the `destroy()` method of the class you can simply assign your `id<MTLBuffer>` (or whatever) pointer to `nil` and the compiler maintains the reference counts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **read the documentation** of your C++ compiler and of the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) handling iOS Metal.

Also, read carefully the documentation of [iOS Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal).

You might also need to read about the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) involved. You might need to use [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and/or [GNU GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to explore that.

If you have some C++ code or Objective C code which could be compiled by a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (specifically GNU GCC, e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in November 2020), you might consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to generate the required glue C++ or Objective C code, a bit like [SWIG](http://swig.org/) does.

And SWIG being open source, you could consider improving it for your needs.

Alternatively, consider generating some glue (C++ or objective C) code using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) (or your script in [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or your C++ metaprogram coded with the help of [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/))